# GET data to PHP method using URLSession - swift

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I am trying to pass some data from my app to php script but it always return me fail like `Could not connect to server`.

But when i copied link to the browser and it works fine as usual. I don't know why it not working in my iOS app.

This is how i send request using URLSession

```
guard let url = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app.php?token=\(deviceToken)") else {
        return
    }
var request = URLRequest(url: url.absoluteURL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil {
            guard let dataReq = data else {
                completionHandler(false, (error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataReq, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]
                if let jsonData = json {
                    print("===== This is jsonData \(jsonData) =====")
                } else {
                    print("===== Cannot Get JSONDATA =====")
                }
            } catch {
                completionHandler(false, (error.localizedDescription))
            }

        } else {
            print("===== Error SENDING REQUEST \((error?.localizedDescription)!)")
            completionHandler(false, (error?.localizedDescription)!)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

**I want to pass parameter named token to my php script**

This is my php file

```
<?php

  $device = $_GET['token'];
  $deviceToken = $device;


  echo $device;
```

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is the local loop back address. I doubt that would work in a simulator, it would point back to the device rather than the computer. find your local IP address and try that... probably starts 192. something

Comment: @Scriptable `127.0.0.1` is my local IP address. I also run it in my actual device.

Comment: you can have a `127.0.0.1` address without any internet connection. its a special IP address and I dont think it will work. the fact that it isn't working should be enough for you to try. your actual device connects via the internet and cannot connect to your computer via a `127.0.0.1` address

Comment: type `ifconfig` into your mac terminal window and you will see multiple network interfaces. you will have one with `127.0.0.1` probably called `lo0` and will probably have others like `en0` which will have another IP address like `192.168.0.3`. try the 192 address

Comment: @Scriptable Thank you sir! Now i have found out why it not work by your explanation. Now it works properly.

Comment: Your welcome. I will add something as an answer so you can close the question.

Comment: As always, delete the `options` parameter in the data task. `.mutableContainers` is pointless in Swift. And the `URLRequest` is redundant, too. Just pass the URL to the data task. A GET request is the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the local loopback IP address which will not work via a physical device or simulator.

type `ifconfig` into your mac terminal window and you will see multiple network interfaces. you will have one with `127.0.0.1` probably called `lo0` and will probably have others like `en0` which will have another IP address like `192.168.0.3`.

You will need to use the local `192.` address to connect to your local machine whilst on the same network.